# There is no option to Add Existing Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

To add a project when i right click to my solution there is no option to

`add -> Existing Project`.

**What should i do to find it?**

[image]

Comment: you can add projects in solution not project in project

Comment: You are right-clicking on a project, not a solution... do you have a solution file?

Comment: Did you bother to Google? [add project to solution visual studio](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=add%20project%20to%20solution%20visual%20studio#q=add+project+to+solution+visual+studio), 2nd link tells you exactly how to do it.

Comment: sorry what you mean to say?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Is adding 1 project to a solution means i can work with it as a library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the File menu to add a project to solution.

```
File -> Add -> Existing Project
```

It looks like some of the default VS settings decide to hide the solution item from the Solution Explorer.

You can show it from `Tools -> Options -> Project And Solutions` and checking the checkbox called "Always Show Solution"

(from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/02/21/did-you-know-how-to-hide-or-show-the-solution-in-solution-explorer-156.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click on a solution to add existing item. You can't add an existing project to a project. There is a hierarchy with the solution being the largest container.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a Solution File (.sln).

You can create a new Blank Solution through the following:

1. On the **File** menu, click **New** and then click **New Project**.
2. In the left pane, select **Installed**, select **Other Project Types**, and
   then select **Visual Studio Solutions** from the expanded list.
3. In the middle pane, select **Blank Solution**.
4. Set the Name and Location values for your solution, then click OK.

After you create a new Solution, add your Existing project to it.

You need to right click your Solution -> Add -> Add Existing Project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a project into another project. You need to create a Solution file(.sln) to hold all your projects. After you have a solution, you can add new project into the solution.

Here is what you need to do:
1. close your current project.
2. in visual studio, File --> new --> project so visual studio will create a solution for you.
3. add your existing project by right click on solution and add existing project.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the hard way that you can't add projects, existing or not, while a build is in progress. I had a build lagging because it was trying to pull nuget and had http timeouts.